# "TypeError: Class constructor IF cannot be invoked without 'new'" while integrating custom CKEditor build to a VueJS 2.* application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I tried integrating **CKEditor 5** to a **VueJS v2.6** application . I opted for custom build option using online builder provided by CKEditor (https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/). As I need custom addition of plugins, custom build is the preferred option.
After taking a basic build , followed the exact same steps mentioned in the below link :
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/frameworks/vuejs-v2.html#integrating-a-custom-build-from-the-online-builder.
I added the editor tag in **Collaboration.vue** component inside **App.vue** .

**Collaboration.vue**

```
<script>
import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';
export default {
  name: 'Collaboration',
  components: {
    editor: Editor,
  },
  data() {
    return {
        editor: Editor,
        editorData: '<p>Content of the editor.</p>',
        editorConfig: {
            // The configuration of the editor.
        }
    };
  }
};
</script>

<template>
 <div>
    <b-card class="mt-2 custom-header-wrapper">
        <h4 slot="header">Editor</h4>
    </b-card>
    <div v-if="editorData" class="preview">
        <editor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></editor>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Below is the error I got on opening **Collaboration.vue** component where I added the editor tag .

[image]

How can I solve this issue?